# Extracting lines based on comma-separated string in another file and write extracted lines to file

Tags: pandas, awk, text-extraction

I have a tab-delimited file that lists the `genomeID` in the first column and its respective `contigIDs`. The contigIDs are comma-separated within the second column (example below)

```
424182.1        H|S1|C933685,H|S1|C449562,H|S1|C172291,H|S1|C1169825
1217675.1       H|S1|C1168525,H|S1|C573086,H|S1|C357867,H|S1|C85072,H|S1|C965427,H|S1|C1724718
585503.1        H|S1|C874141,H|S1|C529585
```

I have another file called `SAMPLE.fasta` that contains contigIDs and the respective sequences in the next line for each contigID (example below)

```
>H|S1|C933685
GAAAGTTCTTGACCTGTGGACAGGCTGTGAATCGGGTTGGACAAGT
>H|S1|C85072
GGAAACGGCTGCTGCCATCCTTGCCCTTCGCCCAAG
>H|S1|C965427
CTCAAGAAATTCGGTATCACCGGTAACTATGAGGCAGTCGAGGTCG
etc...
etc...
etc..
```

Based on this information, I would like to create a `separate file` for each genomeID (example(s) below)

## Output_file: 424182.1.fasta

```
>H|S1|C933685
GAAAGTTCTTGACCTGTGGACAGGCTGTGAATCGGGTTGGACAAGT
```

## Output_file: 1217675.1.fasta

```
>H|S1|C85072
GGAAACGGCTGCTGCCATCCTTGCCCTTCGCCCAAG
>H|S1|C965427
CTCAAGAAATTCGGTATCACCGGTAACTATGAGGCAGTCGAGGTCG
```

Would appreciate any help with `awk and/or pandas`. Thank you in advance for your help with this!

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus.. However, I've been creating contig lists for each genome using `pandas`, and then using another tool (seqtk) to extract said contigs from the `SAMPLE.fasta` file.. This is inefficient since each contig list has at least 400 unique indentifiers, so sought a different approach. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the sequence data ends in a single line (without extending over multiple lines), how about an awk solution:

```
awk -F'\t' '
    NR==FNR {                                   # process SAMPLE.fasta file
        if (FNR % 2) {                          # odd line with contigID
            len = split($0, a, "|")             # extract the contigID
            id = a[len]
            seq[id] = $0                        # assign seq[id] to the line
        } else {                                # even line with sequence
            seq[id] = seq[id] RS $0             # append sequence to seq[id]
        }
        next
    }
    {                                           # process contigIDs file
        fname = $1 ".fasta"                     # filename to write
        len = split($2, a, ",")                 # split the contigIDs
        for (i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
            split(a[i], b, "|")                 # extract the contigID
            if (b[3] in seq) {                  # if the sequence is found
                print seq[b[3]] > fname         # then print it to the file
            }
        }
        close(fname)
    }
' SAMPLE.fasta contigIDs
```

Output:

```
424182.1.fasta file:
>H|S1|C933685
GAAAGTTCTTGACCTGTGGACAGGCTGTGAATCGGGTTGGACAAGT

1217675.1.fasta file:
>H|S1|C85072
GGAAACGGCTGCTGCCATCCTTGCCCTTCGCCCAAG
>H|S1|C965427
CTCAAGAAATTCGGTATCACCGGTAACTATGAGGCAGTCGAGGTCG
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfectly and is quite fast. In fact,  faster than the pandas option that @Corralien provided. This is the only reason why I'm selecting yours as the preferred option.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd

# STEP-1: load sample data and create a Series
data = {}
with open('SAMPLE.fasta') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            id_ = line[1:].strip()
        else:
            data[id_] = line.strip()
sr = pd.Series(data)

# STEP-2: load the list of genome id and create a DataFrame
df = pd.read_table('data.tsv', header=None, names=['genomeID', 'contigIDs'])
df = df.assign(contigIDs=df['contigIDs'].str.split(',')).explode('contigIDs')

# STEP-3: map your series with your dataframe
df = df.assign(Seq=df['contigIDs'].map(sr)).dropna()

# STEP-4: create your files
for filename, df1 in df.groupby('genomeID'):
    with open(f"{filename}.fasta", 'w') as fp:
        for _, row in df1.iterrows():
            fp.write(f">{row['contigIDs']}\n{row['Seq']}\n")
```

Output:

```
# Content of 424182.1.fasta
>H|S1|C933685
GAAAGTTCTTGACCTGTGGACAGGCTGTGAATCGGGTTGGACAAGT

# Content of 1217675.1.fasta
>H|S1|C85072
GGAAACGGCTGCTGCCATCCTTGCCCTTCGCCCAAG
>H|S1|C965427
CTCAAGAAATTCGGTATCACCGGTAACTATGAGGCAGTCGAGGTCG
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This also works great but given the fact that the `awk` version works faster, I had to select hat as the preferred option.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine provided a solution using `biopython and pandas`, so I'm posting it here for completeness' sake..

```
from Bio import SeqIO   # require biopython>=1.7.9
import pandas as pd 

genomes_l = pd.read_csv('test_data.tsv', sep='\t', header=None, names=['genomeID', 'contigID'])

for i, r in genomes_l.iterrows():
    genome_name = r['genomeID']
    contig_ids = r['contigID'].split(',')
    genome_contigs = [rec for rec in SeqIO.parse('SAMPLE.fasta', 'fasta') if rec.id in contig_ids]
    with open(f'out_dir/{genome_name}.fasta', 'w') as handle:
        SeqIO.write(genome_contigs, handle, 'fasta')
```

Thank you all for your help!